# How do I transfer a linux command execution from my linux terminal to run on linux server

Tags: linux, ssh

I do daily backups of files on a remote machine, so before I ftp the files, i have to compress the files on the remote linux server from my linux terminal as below:

$gzip filename.dbf.

So the challenge is that when I close off my linux terminal the process gets disrupted and stops whilst I would want to keep this process running on server until it finishes. So how do i do that.

Comment: tmux, probably.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), which is installed by default on many Linux distros:

```
screen -d -m gzip filename.dbf
```

This will run it in the background in a virtual terminal, you can log out of your session and it will continue running.

If you log back in later and want to check on its progress, just type:

```
screen -r
```